# How can I change the number of workspaces in `Workspace Grid` extension?

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I installed [Workspace Grid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/) extension and the default setup came with 2 x 3 workspaces.

[image]

But, I only want 2 x 2.

[image]

I tried to edit this configuration in https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, however my Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Oncelot **does not support the configuration button**. I think it is because I can't use a newer version of Gnome Shell. Currently, I'm using *GNOME Shell 3.2.2.1*.

How can I change the number of workspaces without using the configuration button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at [mathematicalcoffee BitBucket page](https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension), you can change this configuration through the *extension.js* file.

First, find your Workspace Grid folder inside the extensions folder. Mine is:

```
$ cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com
```

Open *extension.js* file:

```
$ vim extension.js
```

Locate the following lines:

```
//// CONFIGURE HERE (note: you can have at most 36 workspaces)
const WORKSPACE_CONFIGURATION = {
    rows: 2,
    columns: 3
};
```

And change `rows` and `columns` for your desired number of workspaces:

```
rows: 2,
columns: 2
```

Restart your computer.